# Proving a specific group isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism

Let $G=\mathbb{Z}^{\oplus \mathbb{N}}$. That is: $G=\{(a_1,a_2,\ldots)\mid a_i\in\mathbb{Z}, \forall i\in\mathbb{Z}^{>0}\}$. Prove $G\times G\cong G$.

---

What I've done so far:

Let $\phi:G\times G\to G$ such that $\big((a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots),(b_1,b_2,b_3,\ldots)\big)\mapsto(a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2,a_3,b_3,\ldots)$.

First I show that $\phi$ is a homomorphism.

Take $(a,b),(c,d)\in G\times G$. I must show $\phi\big((a,b)(c,d)\big)=\phi\big((a,b)\big)\phi\big((c,d)\big)$.

Well,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}\phi\big((a,b)(c,d)\big)&=(a_1,b_1,c_1,d_1,a_2,b_2,c_2,d_2,\ldots)\\
& =(a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2,\ldots)(c_1,d_1,c_2,d_2,\ldots)\\
&=\phi\big((a,b)\big)\phi\big((c,d)\big).
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
 So $\phi$ is a homomorphism.

Now I must show $\phi$ is bijective. First I show $\phi$ is injective.

Comment: Perhaps you meant $G = \{(a_1, a_2, \dots) | \; a_i \in \mathbb{Z} \;\forall \; i \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}\}$ (i.e. sequences with infinite length)?

Comment: Oops! You're right I did. I misread the problem in the textbook; should get my eyes checked. We're going to let $G=\mathbb{Z}^{\oplus\mathbb{N}}$. Will edit now.

Comment: This is not the correct implication to prove injectivity. For injectivity of $f$, you have to show $f(x) = f(y) \Rightarrow x = y$ (or equivalently $x \neq y \Rightarrow f(x) \neq f(y)$). What you are showing is that $f(x) \neq f(y) \Rightarrow x \neq y$, which holds for all well-defined functions.

Comment: @HarrySmit you're right, apologies. Let me fix this in my scratch work and I'll come back and edit everything thoroughly.

Comment: No problem at all, it's great to see you trying to figure this out yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, $\phi$ is not injective: indeed
$$
\phi\bigl((1,0,\dotsc),(-1,0,\dotsc)\bigr)=(0,0,\dotsc)
$$

An isomorphism can be defined by
$$
\psi\bigl((a_1,a_2,\dotsc),(b_1,b_2,\dotsc)\bigr)=
(a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2,\dotsc)
$$

Comment: Oops! I misread the problem in the textbook; should get my eyes checked. We're going to let $G=\mathbb{Z}^{\oplus\mathbb{N}}$. Will edit now.

Comment: @Aidan I modified the answer. Your $\phi$ is still not injective, of course.

Comment: Thanks, sorry. I'm trying to do a couple of things at once here and of course my current map won't permit an isomorphism, finite or otherwise. I'll do some scribbles using your approach and see if I can break through.

Comment: I'm stuck on showing a homomorphism using the map you provided, so I edited my progress showing what I've tried so far. Pretty confident it's wrong, but I'm not seeing how to separate the terms in the tuple.

Comment: @Aidan Changing the question is not the correct way to go, as it makes the answer not understandable. Please, roll back.

Comment: I haven't changed the question, except for correcting it to the actual question asked in the text (I wrote the question down incorrectly). I'm updating my progress as I go and adjusted my map to use what you provided me.